# Is there anyway to emulate the yellow notification boxes salesforce creates

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there anyway to emulate the yellow notification boxes salesforce creates? They pop up in modal and guide you through things on your first run through, such as this:

[image: Yellow guidance box]

Comment: what is "yellow notification boxes"? what do you mean?

Comment: the modal boxes that come up when salesforce is doing hints.

Comment: Do you mean help texts? Appear when you move mouse over yellow dot with question mark in right from field label?

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd party solution called Walk me http://salesforce.walkme.com/ that does this, plus many other features.

Comment: ... and many others see e.g. http://www.quora.com/User-Experience/What-are-the-alternatives-to-WalkMe.